# Android KitKat cannot read/write internal card

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I had an application which was working with Android **4.2**.
My application was reading a .csv file for searching information.
The application and its files were on the external SD card, that Android KitKat the SD card cannot be read.

So I have moved all the files to the internal card.
So I have created a directory named "mydata" in /storage/emulated/0 which, I presume is the internal card.
Using **ESExplorer** for android I managed to transfer my files
from external SD card to internal.

The newly created dir has r/w permissions (i can see it on ESexplorer)  for "world" and the files are R/W also.

My program, which was running in 4.2, cannot read any more the files.
The Java program says "file does not exists".
Do I have to give some permissions to the program? 
I don't want to root my phone...yet

### Please find the code I use (android/eclipse/juno) with 4.4 development

```
    // test existence of path
    public boolean exists(String path) {
    File f = new File(path);
        boolean b = f.exists();
        return b;
    }
    private void testPath() {
        boolean b;
        putLog("testPath " + "start");
        String path;
        String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        putLog("dir= " + dir);
        // Set the path for the file of books/films/disk etc according to device
        path = "/storage/sdcard0";
        b=fm.exists(path);
        putLog(path+"="+b);

        path = "/storage/emulated/0";
        b=fm.exists(path);
        putLog(path+"="+b);

        path = "/storage/sdcard0/mydata";
        b=fm.exists(path);
        putLog(path+"="+b);

        path = "/storage/emulated/0/mydata";
        b=fm.exists(path);
        putLog(path+"="+b);
        // db is seen R/W access by ESexplorer
        path = "/storage/sdcard0/mydata/db";
        b=fm.exists(path);
        putLog(path+"="+b);

        path = "/storage/emulated/0/mydata/db";
        b=fm.exists(path);
        putLog(path+"="+b);

        putLog("end");
    }
-LOG:
-12-10 07:38:06.137: D/SMV1(12546): getAppPath start
-12-10 07:38:06.137: D/SMV1(12546): testPath start
-12-10 07:38:06.137: D/SMV1(12546): dir= /data/data/com.abf.searchmedia/files
-12-10 07:38:06.137: D/SMV1(12546): /storage/sdcard0=true
-12-10 07:38:06.147: D/SMV1(12546): /storage/emulated/0=true
-12-10 07:38:06.147: D/SMV1(12546): /storage/sdcard0/mydata=true
-12-10 07:38:06.147: D/SMV1(12546): /storage/emulated/0/mydata=true
-//------ db is seen non existent, but ESexplorer sees it and says RW 
-12-10 07:38:06.147: D/SMV1(12546): /storage/sdcard0/mydata/db=false
-12-10 07:38:06.147: D/SMV1(12546): /storage/emulated/0/mydata/db=false
```

Comment: Kitkat still can read from removable media. Only writing is restricted. Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. Is the subject of your post ok? Better: removable card.

Comment: No, my subject is that my Java program don't see the directories and files created. 4.2 can do. 4.4 can't. And this is the same java code.

Comment: The subject of your post is `Androit kitkat cannot read/write internal card`. But that is not the case as you wanted to say `Android kitkat cannot read/write external card` and ment `Android kitkat cannot read/write removable card`. Please tell which directories and files you create and are not visible? Why are you not commenting on the permissions i named?

Comment: Please find the code I use (android/ecpipse/juno) with 4.4 development

Comment: You are complaining `cannot read/write` but you are not checking for `readable/writable`. You only check if some paths `exists`. But what is `fm`? Looks like crucial to know. Your LOG is missing the first check on db. How come? You still did not react on my first comment though. What should `db` be? File or directory?

Comment: `The java program says "file does not exists".`. Please show the used code and output in LogCat.

Comment: fm is the class where Exist is. db is a directory. So the log says that I can access up to db, but not db. db exists and is r/w on the phone (seen through ESexplorer). The log is clear the path up to db returns false when I check it. The path up to mydata is existent.

Comment: That `db` directory does not exist according to your log and code. Please answer my other questions and remarks. This takes already too much time.

Comment: Thats the point, my code don't see db, but db exists on the phone. I don't know how to state this point more clearly. Sorry

Comment: You do not have to state anything more clearly. You were asked to react on my first comment and supply code. Is there any reason why you are so reluctant?

Comment: I have found a solution, but I can't understand the reason the solution is working. I have added in the manifest a permission R/W in EXTERNAL storage, which solve my problem in internal storage. Thnank for your help. Problem closed.

Comment: No YOU did not find a solution. I told you straight away that solution in my first comment. I even asked you twice to react on it. But that was too much asked. And now YOU found it? Congratulations!